# Move from one controller to another with segue and story boards

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have finished the first tutorial in the apple developer tool resources where you make an input, label and button what I want is to make it so when you press the button it takes you to a new scene so i have set up the segue, and i'd it as "testPush" now how do i actually get it to move when i push the button i get an error saying

```
**Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**
```

And the code that it is replying to is this

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloWorldAppDelegate class]));
```

Anyone got any idea's i know u need to add in code for the segue to work however everything i have seen doesn't make sense or its jsut a block of code with little to none instruction on what it means how u get it to work etc. Thanks for any and all help

Other stuff you might need i'm not to sure
Scene one is called: HelloWorldViewController
Scene two is called: HelloWorldViewController2

EDIT

Heres the code from my scripts encase you need that thanks.
HelloWorldViewController.m

```
    #import "HelloWorldViewController.h"
    @interface HelloWorldViewController ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    - (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;
    @end
@implementation HelloWorldViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    self.userName = self.textField.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    if ([nameString length] == 0) {
        nameString = @"World";
    }
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
        if (theTextField == self.textField) {
            [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
        }
        return YES;
    }

@end
```

HelloWorldViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *userName;

@end
```

And main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "HelloWorldAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloWorldAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the segue code you are using?

Comment: Hello, i am not using any code for the segue i control and dragged the button from one scene to another to make the segue and then selected push, all the tutorials i was reading say this is right since im not trying to pass over any data i just want a simple one page to another, for now.

Comment: Hello, yes identifier is testPush thanks.

Comment: Hello sorry what i mean is i allready had the identifier set which is called testPush, still the same issue.

Comment: at the moment i just want to go from one view to the next once i can get that done and working i do plan on moving the label over to the next view. thanks

Comment: is there a button in there to push and where did you declare the button. and also there are tons of sites for learning iOS. ray wanderlich site is very good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a `performseguewithidentifier` in your `IBAction`, something like the following:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

self.userName = self.textField.text;

NSString *nameString = self.userName;
if ([nameString length] == 0) {
    nameString = @"World";
}
NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
self.label.text = greeting;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueId" sender:nil];
}
```

that should push the new for you.

Comment: thank you for all the help, i put this in ran it and i am getting the same error (it complies fine but soon as i press the button it pauses the app and says thread 1: signal SIGABRT at this line of code

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloWorldAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Thank you for all the help do you recommend any good sites/books that i can read over only been doing this for 8 or so hours so u know total noobie lol.

Comment: after looking at debugger it says 

Unknown class HelloWorldViewController2 in Interface Builder file.

Comment: @jphillip724, did you create a fresh single view app from ios 6? if so you dont need to change the app delegate name in main.m it should refer as the generic and original. something like this return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); i think that is why is throwing that exception.

Comment: did you set the class name for the second view controller in IB? it seems it can't find it. in addition i just built your code in a fresh app and it pushes fine.

Comment: Hello i am not using the single view app im using the page one? i will redo it in a sinlge one and ugh that is good u got it working wonder where ive gone wrong and i called the 2nd one HelloWorldViewController2 it doesnt have a .h or .m file for it tho do you think that is the issue?? i will redo in fresh and get back to you asap thanks for all the help.

Comment: imarked this as the accepted answer thanks or all the help i have decided to leave this alone for now and work on that ray's site you linked in onrder to catch up on the mega basics maybe after just 8 hours i was aiming to high? idk but thank you for all of the help its been much appreciated :)